# Apply Simplex method using M-method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to solve the following linear programming problem:

$$\min (3y_1-y_2+2y_3) \\ 3y_1+2y_2-y_3 \leq 9 \\ 5y_2-y_3 \leq 1 \\ 4y_1-y_2 \geq 1 \\ y_1+y_2+y_3 \leq 3 \\ y_1, y_2, y_3 \geq 0$$

In this case we use the $M$-method.

The canonical form of the problem is the following:

$$-\max (-3y_1+y_2-2y_3) \\ 3y_1+2y_2-y_3 +y_4= 9 \\ 5y_2-y_3 +y_5= 1 \\ 4y_1-y_2 -y_6= 1 \\ y_1+y_2+y_3 +y_7= 3 \\ y_i \geq 0, i=1,2, \dots, 7$$

The matrix $A$ ($Ax=b$) is the following:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 5 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
4 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

It doesn't contain the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix, that's why we introduce an artificial variable $y_8 \geq 0$ at the third equation and we have the new system of restrictions:

$$ 3y_1+2y_2-y_3 +y_4= 9 \\ 5y_2-y_3 +y_5= 1 \\ 4y_1-y_2 -y_6+y_8= 1 \\ y_1+y_2+y_3 +y_7= 3 \\ y_i \geq 0, i=1,2, \dots, 7,8$$

Now we will solve the problem with the $M-$method , i.e. we will solve the linear programming problem $\max(-3y_1+y_2-2y_3+My_8), M<<0$ under the new system of restrictions.

I tried to apply the simplex method and I got the following:

$$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 160 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 80 & L_1\\ 
P_5 & 0 & 180 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 60 & L_2\\ 
P_6 & 0 & 200 & 4 & 3 & 2& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 50 & L_3\\ 
P_7 & 0 & 120 & 1 & 2 & 1 &0  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 120 & L_4 \\
 & z & 0 & -30 & -26 & -28 & 0 & 0& 0& 0 &  & L_5 
\end{matrix}$$

$P_1$ gets in the basis, while $P_6$ gets out of the basis.

$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 60 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 3  & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 20 & L_1'=L_1-2L_3'\\ 
P_5 & 0 & 30 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4}  & \frac{3}{2} & 0& 1 & -\frac{3}{4} & 0 & 20 & L_2'=L_2-3L_3'\\ 
P_1 & 30 & 50 & 1 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{2}& 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 100 & L_3'=\frac{L_3}{4}\\ 
P_7 & 0 & 120 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 120 & L_4'=L_4 \\
 & z & 1500 & 0 & -\frac{7}{2} & -13 & 0 & 0&\frac{15}{2} & 0 &  & L_5'=L_5+30L_3' 
\end{matrix}$

And then $P_3$ would get in the basis and $P_4$ would go out of the basis.

But I found that the initial tableau should be the following:

[image]

So could you explain how we apply the Simplex method in such a case?

Comment: I think "$\max(-3y_1+y_2-2y_3+MY-8), M<<0$"  should be "$\max(-3y_1+y_2-2y_3-My_8), M<<0$"

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: How can $P_4 = 160$ in the first tableau satisfy this first constraint $3y_1+2y_2-y_3 +y_4= 9$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter I retried it and now I got this first simplex tableau: $$$$
$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 &  P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & P_8 & \theta &  \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& &\\ 
P_5 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 5 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0& &\\ 
P_8 & 0 & 1 & 4 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0  & 1& &\\ 
P_7 & 0& 3 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 & &\\ 
 & z &  9M& 3M+3 & 2M-1& 2-M & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & &
\end{matrix}$

$$$$

Comment: At my textbook, the values of $z_j-c_j$ are different from mine, namely: $M \ \ \ 4M+3 \ \ \ -M-1 \ \ \ \ 2 \ \ \ 0 \ \ \  0 \ \ \ -M \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ 0$.
$$$$
I found these values doing the operation $L_4'=ML_1+L_4$. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We treat $|M|$ as a very large constant, and $M < 0$ here.  (IMHO, I don't think that assuming $M$ to be negative is a good habit.  Assuming $M > 0$ to be very large and write the objective function as $\max(-3y_1+y_2-2y_3-My_8)$ is better.)

The inital matrix

\begin{matrix}
 B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 &  P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & P_8 & \theta &  \\
  P_4 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& &\\
  P_5 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 5 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0& &\\
  P_8 & M & 1 & 4 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0  & 1& &\\
  P_7 & 0 & 3 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 & &\\
   & z & 0 & 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -M & &
\end{matrix}

You get the error because you multiplied the first row by $M$ and add it to the last row.  In fact, it should be the $P_8$-row instead of the first row: $P_8$ is a basic variable, so the $P_8$-column should have only one non-zero entry.

\begin{matrix}
 B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 &  P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & P_8 & \theta &  \\
  P_4 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 3 &\\
  P_5 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 5 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0& - &\\
  P_8 & M & 1 & 4^* &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0  & 1& \frac14^* &\\
  P_7 & 0 & 3 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 & 3 &\\
   & z & M & 4M+3^* & -M-1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -M & 0 & 0 & &
\end{matrix}

Now we can *delete the $P_8$-column* since it will *never* enter into the basis again.  (It *doesn't* hurt if you leave it here, but you'll need to calculate five more entries which are useless.)

Now, we have a BFS, and the $M$ is eliminated.  We can proceed normally to get the optimal tableau.

\begin{matrix}
    B & c_B &    b & P_1 &    P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 &  P_6 & P_7 &       \theta & \\
  P_4 &   0 & 33/4 &   0 &   11/4 &  -1 &   1 &   0 &  3/4 &   0 &            3 & \\
  P_5 &   0 &    1 &   0 &    5^* &  -1 &   0 &   1 &    0 &   0 &    \frac15^* & \\
  P_1 &  -3 &  1/4 &   1 &   -1/4 &   0 &   0 &   0 & -1/4 &   0 &            - & \\
  P_7 &   0 & 11/4 &   0 &    5/4 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  1/4 &   1 & \frac{11}{5} & \\
      &   z & -3/4 &   0 & -1/4^* &   2 &   0 &   0 &  3/4 &   0 &              & 
\end{matrix}

\begin{matrix}
    B & c_B &     b & P_1 & P_2 &   P_3 & P_4 &    P_5 &  P_6 & P_7 & \theta &  \\
  P_4 &   0 & 77/10 &   0 &   0 & -9/20 &   1 & -11/20 &  3/4 &   0 &      - &  \\
  P_2 &   0 &   1/5 &   0 &   1 &  -1/5 &   0 &    1/5 &    0 &   0 &      - &  \\
  P_1 &  -3 &  3/10 &   1 &   0 & -1/20 &   0 &   1/20 & -1/4 &   0 &      - &  \\
  P_7 &   0 &   5/2 &   0 &   0 &   5/4 &   0 &   -1/4 &  1/4 &   1 &      - &  \\
      &   z & -7/10 &   0 &   0 & 39/20 &   0 &   1/20 &  3/4 &   0 &        &
\end{matrix}

Therefore, the optimal solution is $\left(\frac{3}{10},\frac15,0,\frac{77}{10},0,0,\frac52,0\right)^T$ and the optimal value is $-\frac{7}{10}$.

Comment: I see... This is the optimal solution for $\max (-3y_1+y_2-2y_3+My_8)$ under the new system of restrictions. The initial problem was to find $- \max (-3y_1+y_2-2y_3)$ without $y_8$ at the system of restrictions. How can we find now the solution for the initial problem?

Comment: @Evinda The solution is the *same* for both LPPs, so the optimal value for the original value is $\frac{7}{10}$